# Joomla: what is wrong with my plugins XML - config-section is not shown?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I am trying to upgrade an old mambot. It's possible that there are still bugs in the code, but even the config-screen does not show up, only the basic pi-parameters are there, none of mine. What am I missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<extension type="plugin" group="content" version="1.6" method="upgrade">
    <name>mb_append</name>
    <creationDate>June 08, 2013</creationDate>
    <version>1.1</version>

    <author>Michael Baas</author>
    <authorName>Michael Baas</authorName>
    <authorEmail>michael@mbaas.de</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>mbaas.de</authorUrl>

    <description>
        <![CDATA[
    <p>Very simple bot to append constant <i>(configureable)</i> text (i.e. &lt;br&gt;-tags!) to the
    article and the output. 'Output' includes the "ReadMore..."-Link (but not the
    navigation). (However, if you absolutely
    need this, let me know and I may implement it, but it's a bit tricky, so I would only
do this if somebody can convince me he needs it ;)</p>

<p>In case you want to insert multiple texts between the output of other plugins etc., you can
    create further instances of this plugin by simply renaming the PHP and XML in the
    installation-ZIP AND by adjusting the names in the XML and then just install your
'new' mambot! :)</p>

<p><b>Links</b>&nbsp;<i>(automatically open in new window)</i>:
<ul>
<li><a href="http://mbaas.de" target="_blank">Michael's Homepage</a>
</ul>
]]>
</description>

<copyright>(c) 2013 Michael Baas</copyright>
<license>GPL</license>
<files>
    <filename plugin="mb_append">mb_append.php</filename>
</files>

<config>
    <fields name="config">
        <fieldset name="basic">
            <field name="txt_app" type="text" default="" label="Append 2 article" description="The text you want to append to the article" size="40" />
            <field name="txt" type="text" default="" label="Append 2 output" description="The text you want to append to the output" size="40"/>
            <field name="look4txt" type="radio" value="1" label="Check if txt already there?" description="Check if the specified text has already been added to the text and do not add again if this option is activated.">
                <option value="0">No</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
            </field>

            <field name="excat" type="text" default="" label="Categories to EXCLUDE" description="Comma-separated list of IDs"  size="40"/>
            <field name="exid" type="text" default="" label="Article-IDs to EXCLUDE" description="Comma-separated list of IDs OR a 'less-than'-sign (arrow-left) followed by ONE number to exclude all IDs smaller than thew number you specified!" size="40" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>

</extension>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `<fields name="config">` to `<fields name="params">`. This might work then.

Comment: Thanks - had not thought of that :(

Comment: Good. It's also advisable to change the version in the <extension type="plugin" group="content" version="1.6" method="upgrade"> to 3.0 or other Joomla!™ version to be used.